# Why does ssh-add return 1, causing my bash script to exit?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that exits after `ssh-add`.
Here is a really simple script to show my issue:

```
#!/bin/bash -eu
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add
echo $?
echo "hello"
```

I don't ever get to the `echo $?` or `echo "hello"` because `ssh-add` returns a 1.

So the `-e` will exit out because of this.

I just don't know why `ssh-add` returns a 1 and not a 0.  All the keys in `~/.ssh` are set up properly.

Comment: Replace `ssh-add` with `ssh-add -vvv`.

Comment: Read the error message written by `ssh-add` to stderr, which describes _why_ it's considering itself to have failed. You need to include that error message in the question you're asking here for the question to be answerable.

Comment: (and on a different topic, see [BashFAQ #105](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) -- particularly the exercises section -- describing why `set -e` is a bad idea in general).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy -- I thought I did say ssh-add returns a 1.  If I try to print out the stderr or by doing `ssh-add &> /tmp/out.txt` it is empty.

But I do appreciate the BashFAQ #105 so I'm going to take that approach and not use the -e .. thanks.

Comment: You did say it returned 1; you did not say that nothing was written to stderr. You'd be surprised how many people ask a question about why something failed without running it in a context that lets them read its stderr.